# Modifications of free nucleotides

Tags: rna, transcription, nucleic-acids

We know that RNA can get modified post transcriptionally ([RNA modification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RNA_modification)). So when the RNA is degraded, is it possible for such modifications to still be present on the individual nucleotides -- such that when the nucleotides are recycled for constructing another RNA, those modifications persist?

Comment: It's unlikely that a chemically modified nucleotide would be recycled into a new RNA.

Comment: Why is that? As in which chemical reactions during the course of degradation -> recycling are likely to remove the modification(s)?